# conky weather forecast isn't working

Tags: conky, weather

I'm new here. I'm using Kubuntu 14.10 - and here's my first question:
I'm running conky; the only thing that is not working is the weather forecast. Conky is telling me: "city not found" (the code ist for Salzburg, Austria - my home town).

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Bitstream Vera Sans Mono:size=9
xftalpha 0.8
update_interval 1.0
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_title conky
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 0
own_window_type normal
own_window_colour black
double_buffer yes
minimum_size 260 5
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
stippled_borders 0
border_margin 4
border_width 0
default_color white
default_shade_color black
default_outline_color black
alignment top_right
gap_x 12
gap_y 12
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 1
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes
mpd_host localhost
mpd_portPort 6060
#mpd_password 

TEXT
```

I've taken my conky-file from this link: [conkyrc in Ubuntu-Studio Style](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/_attachment?target=Conky%2Fbeispielrc.txt). With the following line conky should show the weather forecast...

```
${execi 300 /home/matthias/scripts/weather.sh AUXX0018}
```

I downloaded the weather.sh file and added the weather-code for my hometown Salzburg, Austria: AUXX0018.

But - this configuration doesn't work. Conky (or weather.sh?) can't find the city...

Just tell me, if you need more information about my configuration.

Comment: Can you provide the weather.sh?
Check which API is weather.sh working on for retrieving weather forecast.
Find and Add the weather code for that API.